# Can we connect the gateway only once in hypeledger fabric using node SDK

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I need to help with my query which related to hyperledger fabric gateway connection to client though node sdk. I wrote some API's which is connected to the fabric network using below code.

```
const ccpPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'config', 'connection.json');

const gateway = new Gateway();

await gateway.connect(ccpPath, {
    wallet,
    identity: Username,
    discovery: {
        enabled: true,
        asLocalhost: false
    }

});
```

Now I have to use the above code to connect each and every time controller which call API's, however, I want to use it onetime so Once the connection made to the network I don't need to connect again and again. 
Is there is some way to implement it? if possible suggest to me so I can implement it in my API's.
Please let me know if there is anything more information need?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes sure.

inglobe in a connect function and declare the gateway as external to the function.

```
let gateway;
function connect() {
  const ccpPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'config', 'connection.json');

  gateway = new Gateway();

  await gateway.connect(ccpPath, {
    wallet,
    identity: Username,
    discovery: {
        enabled: true,
        asLocalhost: false
    }

  });
}
```

Next from app.js or starting point of your app, call the function and you are connected.
You don't need to connect each time, you can connect once.

Comment: Hi @RicNtt, Thanks for the solution, however still I have some query like how can I pass username as identity to this function?

Comment: Hi @RicNtt I have implement your answer however getting some issue which I need to discuss.

Comment: Hey, I am using this solution and it works correctly in my project. Set this as answer if it solved, you probably are experiencing some other issues related to your project. Maybe they are more related to Node.js than the SDK.

Comment: Np. Please set this as "ANSWER". Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Gateways are designed to be re-used, in fact you should avoid constantly creating and disconnecting gateways as this can lead to network problems.

The one thing to realise with Gateways is that they have a 1-1 relationship with identities as well as the fabric network (but not channels, a gateway can connect to more than 1 channel) . So the correct use of gateways is to have a gateway for each different identity for your network and re-use this gateway.

If you plan to have a lot of different identities connecting then you may want to consider using a stale policy for gateways as they will keep network connections, so for example if an identity doesn't interact with the network in a while then you could disconnect that gateway and create a new one for that identity when they try to interact later.